# Return the elements present exactly once in an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am a beginner in Ruby. Can anyone help me to write code for this, please?

Given an Array, return the elements that are present exactly once in the array.

For example, it should pass the following test cases:

- returns `[1,4,5]`, given `[1,2,2,3,3,4,5]`
- returns `[1,3]`, given `[1,2,2,3,4,4]`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  If so, post your current efforts and we'll make suggestions.

Comment: SO, the great homework auto-solver...muhaha :)

Answer (score 5):

Put the items in an array.  `a = [1,2,2,3,4,4]`  Then run a few filters to get the items you want.

```
a.group_by { |x| x }.reject { |k,v| v.count > 1 }.keys

#=> [1,3]
```

*Updated* With Stefan's `keys` suggestion.

Comment: You can use `.keys` instead of `.map { |k,v| k }`

Comment: nit-picking: the simple action of using plurals for collection makes code so much clear. Also, I'd use positive logic: `xs.group_by { |x| x }.select { |k, vs| vs.size == 1 }.keys`.

Comment: This solution is faster for larger arrays

Comment: yeah thnx a lot..its working.. can u please suggest what should i do if i want to take the input array from keyboard? gets.chomp.to_i is not working

Comment: Taking the input as a comma separated list from a user would make a great 2nd question. I'll search for your post and help answer there too.

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
p a.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1}
# >> [1, 4, 5]


a = [1,2,2,3,4,4]
p a.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1}
# >> [1, 3]
```

**Benchmarks**

```
require 'benchmark'

a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]

n = 1000000
Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report('priti') { n.times { a.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1} } }
  x.report('Jason') { n.times { a.group_by { |x| x }.reject { |k,v| v.count > 1 }.keys } }
  x.report('rogerdpack2') { n.times {
    bad = {}
    good = {}
    a.each{|v|
      if bad.key? v
        # do nothing
      else
        if good.key? v
          bad[v] = true
          good.delete(v)
        else
          good[v] = true;
        end
      end
    }
    good.keys            
  }
 }
end
```

with this result

```
 priti             3.152000   0.000000   3.152000 (  3.247000)
 Jason             4.633000   0.000000   4.633000 (  4.845000)
 rogerdpack2       3.853000   0.000000   3.853000 (  3.886000)
```

and with a larger array:

require 'benchmark'

a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]*5 + [33,34]

```
n = 1000000
Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report('priti') { n.times { a.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1} } }
  x.report('Jason') { n.times { a.group_by { |x| x }.reject { |k,v| v.count > 1 }.keys } }
  x.report('rogerdpack2') { n.times {
    bad = {}
    good = {}
    a.each{|v|
      if bad.key? v
        # do nothing
      else
        if good.key? v
          bad[v] = true
          good.delete(v)
        else
          good[v] = true;
        end
      end
    }
    good.keys            
  }
 }
 x.report('priti2') { n.times { a.uniq.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1} }}
end
```

you get result:

```
                  user     system      total        real
 priti            60.435000   0.000000  60.435000 ( 60.769151)
 Jason            10.827000   0.016000  10.843000 ( 10.978195)
 rogerdpack2       9.141000   0.000000   9.141000 (  9.213843)
 priti2           15.897000   0.000000  15.897000 ( 16.007201)
```

Comment: can u please suggest what should i do if i want to take the input array from keyboard? gets.chomp.to_i is not working i thnk..

Comment: @user2536488 that's too much for a comment, please start a new question

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
b = {}
a.each{|v|
  b[v] ||= 0
  b[v] += 1
}
b.select{|k, v| v == 1}.keys
```

and here's a potentially faster one (though more complex) that is hard coded to look for items "just listed once":

```
a = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5]
bad = {}
good = {}
a.each{|v|
  if bad.key? v
    # do nothing
  else
    if good.key? v
      bad[v] = true
      good.delete(v)
    else
      good[v] = true;
    end
  end
}
good.keys
```

Comment: with larger array I would use `a.uniq.select{|i| a.count(i) == 1}` .. :)

Comment: nice and succinct.  I've added it to the benchmarks.  My hunch is that using #count causes O(N^2) complexity...

Comment: @roger... Thank you very much for your all efforts... :)))

Comment: You can use `Hash.new(0)` to avoid having to `||= 0`.